# Scheduler in Java

Tags: java, servlets, scheduler, jboss-4.0.x

I need some assistance in implementing a scheduler which runs parallel with the other processing. I found `quartz scheduler` for many of my searches on the web. But, I need something which is inbuilt and can run concurrently with other processes and not any external libraries

I checked with [scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). But, this has not option for parallel execution.

Can anyone please suggest in this regard?? My requirement is that, a java function has to run at every fixed intervals soon after the server starts. This will be known by the servlet start and I will have to initiate the scheduler in the init().

Comment: What exactly do mean with "parallel execution"? Executors can be configured to do that, AFAIK.

Comment: You're talking about Servlets so I guess you're somewhat using JEE. Why not using the EJB timer service ? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-basicexamples004.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My requirement is that, a java function has to run at every fixed
>   intervals soon after the server starts

- To begin with, you can start using [java.util.Timer.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) Here is a good [link on usage of Timer class.](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html)
- Using quartz scheduler is always a better option, but Timer can be a quick way to start off with. You can find some help to start using [Quartz Scheduler in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/)
- Alternatively, you can also opt for [ScheduledExecutorService in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). I would prefer this option over `java.util.Timer`

Comment: Hi, 1. Can concurrency happen using `java.util.timer` ? 2. I do not wish to use any external libraries in my source and so quartz is not an option certainly. 3. I checked for it. As, I have mentioned in the question itself..

Comment: Yes, Timer will spawn a new thread (which executes concurrently). I have mentioned quartz just an additional option, depending on requirements. If you do not have such requirements go for executor or timer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on timers?? Need some examples, which I'm not finding enough on the web.

Comment: @PavanKumar : Please refer usage link provided in my post. It has basic example of timer usage.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to define a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), and to start a Quartz scheduler from its `contextInitialized` method.

`contextInitialized` is called on application deployment/reload on your application server, thus your scheduler can be initialized `soon after the server starts`.

Comment: I do not wish to use any external libraries in this case. Can you please suggest me something inbuilt in Java and can be used for my requirement??